# Cisco Catalyst 3550 Switch - VLAN ACL question

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, access-control-list

I can't seem to get Vlan ACLs to work properly. I want to be able to get to servers on the 10.100.x.x network as well as the 10.200.x.x network when I'm connected through the VPN. But, I want to prevent the 10.100.x.x network from seeing 10.200.x.x

Currently, I have 2 Vlans:

```
interface Vlan111
 description "vlan 111" 
 ip address 10.100.1.1 255.255.255.0


interface Vlan222
 description "vlan 222"
 ip address 10.200.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group vlan222_acl in
 ip access-group vlan222_acl out
```

And I have 2 servers connected to each VLAN:

```
!--- the below port is connected to a windows machine with static ip address 10.100.1.10 and gateway 10.100.1.1
interface FastEthernet0/4                            
 description server 1
 switchport access vlan 111
 switchport mode access

!--- the below port is connected to a windows machine with static ip address 10.200.1.10 and gateway 10.200.1.1
interface FastEthernet0/5                            
 description server 2
 switchport access vlan 222
 switchport mode access
```

The problem is when I configure vlan222_acl.

Here is what I enter:

```
ip access-list extended vlan222_acl
 deny icmp 10.100.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.200.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

But here is what gets applied to the running config:

```
ip access-list extended vlan222_acl
 deny icmp 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
!--- the above line is not what I actually entered in the terminal, for some reason 
!--- the source and dest ip addresses are getting replaced with zeros
```

Because of the above line, everyone now is unable to ping the server at 10.200.1.10. When I remove the line, ie 
`no deny icmp 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0`
then I can ping it again.

How can I restrict only 10.100.x.x from being able to ping 10.200.x.x?

Many thanks in advance for the help!
G

Answer (score 1):

you need to reverse your netmasks...i.e., 
instead of 255.255.0.0 use 0.0.255.255

Example:

```
ip access-list standard external_traffic
 deny   172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255
 deny   192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
```

Additionally, you do understand that you need a router between VLAN'd subnets, right? (not trying to sound snotty, I'm just not sure of your experience level)

edit: 
Is there a reason you're using /24 subnets for address assignment, but /16's for your ACL?

My suggestion would be to toss out the ACL on 222, and put restrictions on the 111 subnet, since that's what you're actually wanting to restrict anyway.

```
ip access-list extended block-icmp
deny icmp 10.100.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.200.1.0 0.0.0.255
permit ip any any
!
interface vlan 111
 ip access-group block-icmp in
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.



I tried the following:


deny icmp 10.100.0.0 0.0.255.255 10.200.0.0 0.0.255.255


which seemed to effectively block the 10.100.1.10 host from getting to 10.200.1.10, but it also ended up blocking everyone else from getting to it (same as my initial problem).


I.E: I also tried pinging from a host on a different network (192.168.x.x), and before adding the above command, I was able to ping and get to 10.200.x.x, but after adding it, I'm no longer able to.

Comment: In all access-lists you need an allow rule at the end of the list if you want to access *anything*. By default a Cisco ACL is implicit deny.
@Greeblesnort: The Cisco 3550 is layer 3 capable and can route between VLANs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either: what ends up happening is everyone gets blocked when I apply the deny rule, then everyone gets access again once I apply the permit any any command :S

Comment: @HampusLi - I should have known that, as I've got a 3550 floating around somewhere in my datacenter, even though it's only doing L2.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the ACL to VLAN 222 for both incoming and outgoing traffic and the ACLs are not stateful. This means that they won't allow return traffic by their own, you will have to add an implicit rule for that. So, in this case, you're blocking the return traffic.

One solution would be to add another rule for the return traffic on the same ACL but what I think would be best, is to have two different ACLs for incoming and outgoing traffic, if you really need them.

You can also try to use **reflexive** ACLs which is a good way to allow return traffic. Check here for more details: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/security/command/reference/srfreflx.html

Here are some additional tips that may help t-shooting.

- `show access-list NAME/NUMBER` shows the number of hits for each rule show you can see which rules are matching and denying or allowing packets. This wouldn't help much in your case since you have the same ACL on both directions and you wouldn't know where it matched.
- If you add *log* at the end of each rule (i.e. `deny icmp 10.100.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.200.1.0 0.0.0.255 log`) the switch will log each match which the you can revies with `show logging` This is CPU intensive though so try not to leave it on for long, just for t-shooting.